# Installing rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.0_6952.20130315.tar.gz

Tags: wireless, drivers, apt, compiling, tar

Hi while trying to get the drivers for my "**EDIMAX AC600 Dual-Band High Gain Wi-Fi USB Adapter**" I run into the following problem:

After `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

and `cd /home/"USERNAME"`

I try to `tar vxzf rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.0_6952.20130315.tar.gz`

but I get:

```
tar (child): rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.0_6952.20130315.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

as result

I can't find the folder where it is supossed to be, the sudo apt-get doesn't show me where it put it.

I am Running Xubuntu and I'm totally new to it, borrowed that laptop a week ago for my travels.

Thank your for you attention

Comment: The instructions in the manual (basically the same, 7 years later) completely neglect the part where you have to get the files off the CD and on to your hard drive. That's why you got a file not found error.

Answer (score 9):

Simply copy and paste each command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

You should be all set.

You have compiled the driver for your current running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later one, also known as linux-image, re-compile:

```
cd ~/rtl8812au
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

Glad it's working!

Comment: Please see my edit above and if my answer has been helpful, please accept it.

Comment: The instructions I have that came with the device (also an Edimax wifi) say to use insmod instead of modprobe. Do they both work?

Comment: @jcollum The process in this 7 year old answer is obsolete. Please start your own new question and I'll be very happy to help.

Comment: OK. I think I can't do much without the driver from Edimax, so I'll wait until they respond to my support request. I'm in Ubuntu 20 and that seems to be a problem, the last one I tried the manufacturer said they didn't have working drivers for Ubuntu 20. I had to return it.

Comment: We can fix it without manufacturers drivers. Please post a new question. @jcollum

Comment: here you go: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361907/how-do-i-get-a-wireless-network-to-come-up-when-it-stays-down-after-telling-it-t

Answer (score 4):

Now this driver has been added to Ubuntu repositories.

It can be installed to Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 by running

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

The current version is 4.3.8.

Comment: Does this mean if I run that my new wifi USB dongle will have a driver after I reboot?

Comment: It depends on which dongle you have and which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Edimax 7822UAC, Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 1):

Special note! :D I have D-Link AC1200 USB adapter. It's a Revision D tho!!! So I kept digging and digging... turns out, revision C had a different chip, than mine!
So for those of you digging that can't get yours working,

OR if you know you have a Realtek RTL8812BU or RTL8822BU chipset, then try the following 1 line at a time in your command prompt. Worked for me and I'm so stoked right now! :D :) I had to dig and dig tho, so I thought I would drop this gem here since all my searches for DWA 182 d1 led me here at one point or another. Hope this helps someone. :)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git
git clone https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu.git
cd rtl8822bu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```