# Five reboots after installation, many parts of the system (terminal, file browser, drivers) stop working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, google-chrome

So this is the second time this has happened. I fresh install, everything works fine for the first 5 reboots. Then upon reboot, I cannot open the file manager or terminal, and my audio driver is gone? Sound no longer works. I really want to use Ubuntu, I love it so far in the past 2-4 hours, but man, this is killing me. I cannot open terminal OR file manager.

I also can no longer watch videos on YouTube. Software Updater app seems to be unable to connect for some reason.

Switching from proprietary nvidia driver to open source allows my sound to come back.

Wifi adapter is also not working well...

I think this could be related to Chrome remote desktop. I'm on a mission to remove it.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 ??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You haven't told us your version of Ubuntu, nor if you install any non-repository software (ie. add PPA's other software from other sources, especially if it was for a different environment and is thus creating your issue). If you can't access a terminal in gui, you could switch to a text terminal with ctrl+alt+f4 etc.

Comment: I tried using crtl + alt + f4 to bring up a text terminal, but it didn't work either. Neither does crtl+ alt + t/clicking on the terminal app.  I am using 18.04 ubuntu lts. I am using the basic set up. I did clean install from usb to a 240gb ssd. Only issues I ran into were installing wifi driver 'rtl8812AU' which I followed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/491263/installing-rtl8812au-linux-v4-2-0-6952-20130315-tar-gz . And that's it. I have an nvidia gtx 450s  ghx card if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem. Yes, it is because of Chrome Remote Desktop. It is necessary to uninstall. Try accessing a virtual terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> (this worked in my case) or using emacs eshell, and use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove chrome-remote-desktop
reboot
```

This worked for me.